# Mutiple has_one of the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, relationship

Got a really interesting situation with all that `has_one` and `belongs_to` relationships when Rails loads its dependant models in an inversed manner.

Let us have a model `Couple` with two related models of the same class, `User`:

```
class Couple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :male, class_name: "User"
  has_one :female, class_name: "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :couple
end
```

In this situation, when we create a `Couple` and assign it two instances of `User`, we will get into this:

```
# create all the stuff
couple = Couple.new
he = User.create name: 'Bob'
she = User.create name: 'Sara'
couple.male = he
couple.female = she
couple.save

# here's where the gap begins:
couple.male.name # => 'Bob'
couple.female.name # => 'Sara'

# Ok, so far so good...
Couple.find(couple.id).male.name # => 'Bob'

# What's the ..?!
Couple.find(couple.id).female.name # => 'Bob'
```

And what I've seen in the console performing all these, is this:

```
> couple.female.name
'Sara'
# nothing happens as the model is loaded already

> Couple.find(couple.id).female.name
SELECT  `couples`.* FROM `couples` WHERE `couples`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`couple_id` = 2 LIMIT 1
'Bob'
# sure, here's the trouble!
```

Hmmm... That's not good... Searching over the Internet guided me to this: I created two classes, `MaleUser` and `FemaleUser`, both derived from `User` model. And changed the `belongs_to :couple` to a `belongs_to :couple, foreign_key: :his_id` and `... :her_id`. Yet, the same result I seen on the screen.

My question is, why the hell this happens and how to perform that loading in a correct manner? So that `Couple.find(couple_id).she` would gave me the proper object?

**UPD:** tables structure:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.integer :couple_id
  # ...
end

create_table :couples do |t|
  t.integer :his_id
  t.integer :her_id
  # ...
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also include the table migration / SQL table structure for both `User` and `Couple`?

Comment: @Pete if this helps... Yet, there's nothing really interesting or supernatural there...

Answer (score 0):

The relationship for the `users` in `Couple` needs to be a `belongs_to` relationship and not `has_one`. E.g:

```
class Couple < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  belongs_to :male, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'his_id'
  belongs_to :female, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'her_id'
end
```

This tells ActiveRecord that a `Couple` has two `User` object relations. One named `male` that can be retrieved with the ID found in the `his_id` column of the Couple table and one named `female` who's ID is found in the `her_id` column.

Whereas `has_one` would look for this relationship data on the `Users` table (which doesn't exist). The users table only references the `couple_id` and not whether the user is the male or female user for the `Couple` relationship.

Comment: But does that make any sense? Like saying "couple belongs to male and female" it's just... weird... Whilst I suppose Rails developers added those methods for that verbal correctness.

Comment: The methods are named that way in ActiveRecord to indicate in which class the relationship is stored. 90% of the time it works well with the English language (comment belongs_to blog post etc) however it will never read perfectly in 100% of all situations. The alternative is to use Single Table Inheritance (STI) so Couple has_one Female and has_one Male rather than multiple Users. I don't know if this is just a hypothetical example, but it's important to remember that a Couple could also be male/male or female/female. So effectively a Couple has_many Users which also reads better